# Android : I would like to put Custom Chrome Tab inside a Fragment in an Activity

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-fragments, chrome-custom-tabs

I have an activity that has a TabLayout. Inside each Tab, there is a Fragment. I want to show different webcontent form a URL in each Fragment.

Is this possible ?

From what I researched, Chrome Tabs seems to show it on a separate full page by itself with an X or <- icon on the left side. But this fails my requirement.

I can achieve this using a WebView but given that ChromeTabs can do prefetch and token etc. I would like to investigate this option.

I went through lot of documentation, so please dont cut this off as no research.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot put use Chrome Tabs for that purpose. I moved ahead with `WebView`.